# Insert an additional element in the JSON output

Tags: json, sql-server

I need to figure out how to insert additional elemnents in the JSON being returned by SQL Server.

```
Create Table dbo.Project (Id int IDENTITY(1,1), [Description] NVARCHAR(100), [Note] NVARCHAR(100))

Insert Into Project ([Description],[Note]) VALUES('Daphne','Ocala county - Barn')
Insert Into Project ([Description],[Note]) VALUES('Sunny','Riverdon county - Prison')
Insert Into Project ([Description],[Note]) VALUES('Sasha','Sommer county - School')

SELECT (SELECT  CAST(Id AS nvarchar) 'ExternalRefNbr', [Description], [Note] FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) FROM Project
```

The Select query gives me this output.

```
{"ExternalRefNbr":"1","Description":"Daphne","Note":"Ocala county - Barn"}
{"ExternalRefNbr":"2","Description":"Sunny","Note":"Riverdon county - Prison"}
{"ExternalRefNbr":"3","Description":"Sasha","Note":"Sommer county - School"}
```

Now I would like to know how to insert another element in this JSON.
The output I would like is

```
{"ExternalRefNbr":{"value":"1"},"Description":{"value":"Daphne"},"Note":{"value":"Ocala county - Barn"}}
{"ExternalRefNbr":{"value":"2"},"Description":{"value":"Sunny"},"Note":{"value":"Riverdon county - Prison"}}
{"ExternalRefNbr":{"value":"3"},"Description":{"value":"Sasha"},"Note":{"value":"Sommer county - School"}}
```

**How do I get the "value" in there? Any suggestions are appreciated.**

Comment: Alias your fields like `[ExternalRefNbr.value]` instead of just `ExternalRefNbr`

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick: Varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: For SQL Server 2022 you may use `JSON_OBJECT()`: `SELECT JSON_OBJECT('ExternalRefNbr': JSON_OBJECT('value': cast(Id as nvarchar(30))), 'Description': JSON_OBJECT('value': Description), 'Note': JSON_OBJECT('value': Note)) FROM #Project`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alias your fields using `.` to build document structure. For your case, you can do this:

```
drop table if exists #Project
create table #Project
(
    Id int identity(1, 1),
    Description nvarchar(100),
    Note nvarchar(100)
)

insert into #Project
values
('Daphne', 'Ocala county - Barn'),
('Sunny', 'Riverdon county - Prison'),
('Sasha', 'Sommer county - School')

select
    (
        select
            [ExternalRefNbr.value] = cast(Id as nvarchar(30)),
            [Description.value] = Description,
            [Note.value] = Note
        for json path, without_array_wrapper
    )
from #Project
```